# Magento database error

Tags: magento-1.9, database, error

I am working with existing database back up. And getting below error when i try to setup.

This error is coming in ubuntu only

Error:

```
SELECT `e`.* FROM `catalog_category_entity` AS `e` WHERE (`e`.`entity_type_id` = '3') AND (`e`.`path` REGEXP '^1(/[0-9]+){1,}$') ORDER BY `e`.`path` ASC
```

Comment: what's the error? what's the mysql version?

Comment: @Marius, mySQL version in "phpMyAdmin 4.5.2" and i am getting below error "SELECT `e`.* FROM `catalog_category_entity` AS `e` WHERE (`e`.`entity_type_id` = '3') AND (`e`.`path` REGEXP '^1(/[0-9]+){1,}$') ORDER BY `e`.`path` ASC"

Comment: is the mysql version 4.5.2 or the phpmyadmin version?

Comment: @Marius, it is phpmyadmin version

Comment: that's not important. what's the mysql version. Run this query `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "%version%";`

Comment: I think this mysql, innodb_version - 5.6.30-76.3